# Нужен ли meta-тег keywords?

Tags: html5, seo, теги

Мета-тег `keywords`, как описано в современной документации, не имеет значения для поисковых роботов, тем не менее на всех сайтах этот тег используется.

У меня *самописная CMS*, нужно ли добавить поле `keywords` в таблицу *БД*  для всех страниц (с последующим выводом в html) или это не даст никакого эффекта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, с тех пор как поисковики научились разбирать текст на страницах, они не просто перестали придавать значение этому тэгу, но и намеренно игнорируют его.

Answer (score 4):

Согласно [официальному блогу Google](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) эта поисковая машина **игнорирует этот мета тэг**. А Bing даже использует этот мета тэг как **сигнал спама** (см. [статью на SearchEngineLand](http://searchengineland.com/the-meta-keywords-tag-lives-at-bing-why-only-spammers-should-use-it-96874)). Побочным эффектом использования этого мета тега является то, что ваши конкуренты будут знать вашу стратегию ключевых слов. Когда вы используете этот мета тег и перечисляете их на ваших веб-страницах, вы по существу передаете им стратегию ключевых слов на блюде.

Ответ на поставленный вопрос: смело игнорируйте этот мета тэг.

Answer (score 3):

По непроверенным на 2015 год данным только [Bing](https://www.bing.com/) продолжает использовать этот meta-тег, а остальные крупные поисковики его игнорируют.

Answer (score 1):

На моей практике нет ни одного сайта, которому бы в ранжирование поспособствовал этот метатег. Напротив, всем своим клиентам на всякий случай рекомендую удалять keywords из документов участвующих в продвижении. 
Вообще meta keywords является фактором определения релевантности в формуле ранжирования, но его вес в формуле так мал, что положительного влияния практически не оказывает.